# Rift Gameplay - Synergy Crystal

Tags: rift

[image]On the Rift Gameplay "Synergy Crystal" how do I add the set bonus stats into the crystal.  Been told a lot of different things but got steered in the wrong direction.  Just returning back to playing Rift and have a lot to learn but it would be a big help if I was being told the truth on how to get the set bonus stats into the crystal (do i buy it, make it, quest it etc;).  Thank you very much and please help.[image: T'Scain's Ranger Crystal]

Answer (score 1):

You activate the bonuses by equipping armor (left side) that is part of the set. Set membership will be displayed on the tooltip for the armor piece.

You are wearing level 65 armor with a level 60 synergy crystal that are not from the same expansion, so none of the armor in that screenshot will contribute to T'Scain's set.

As of this writing - as well as of the time of question submission - the level cap is 70, and there are even more new sets and crystals, so everything in your screenshot is outdated. It is not worth trying to activate a synergy crystal until you are at level cap.

The general way to do so is (1) get armor from expert dungeons, raids, and/or the RIFT store (for ingame currency OR real money) that has a set and (2) buy a crystal for the set from the RIFT store (for ingame currency, usually also gated by faction reputation).  Note that sometimes an armor piece needs to be upgraded to count towards a set.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the crystals only work with sets purchased from the rift store.

Comment: Can you provide the source of your information or any more concrete information?